# Cross-platform type checking with multiprocessing Pipe in python

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I have an application which uses Processes, and Pipes to communicate between them. This needs to be cross-platform (at least Windows and OS X). The code works fine but what I'm struggling with is type sanity checking because on OS X:

```
>>> from multiprocessing import Pipe
>>> a,b = Pipe()
>>> type(a)
<class 'multiprocessing.connection.Connection'>
```

whereas on Windows:

```
>>> from multiprocessing import Pipe
>>> a,b = Pipe()
>>> type(a)
<class 'multiprocessing.connection.PipeConnection'>
```

I am using python 3.3.3 on both platforms. What I want to do is have statements like:

```
assert isinstance(conn, Connection)
```

Is there a clean way to do this in a platform-agnostic way? Or would I have to do OS checks everywhere to differentiate between `Connection` and `PipeConnection`?

Comment: Why does it matter that the types are 'different'?

Comment: Because if I want to do type checking it matters. PipeConnection doesn't exist on OS X, and isinstance(conn, Connection) is False on Windows.

Comment: Basically I am writing a function that is intended to be the target of a Process, and ideally I'd like to verify that the arg passed to it is a Connection/PipeConnection.

Comment: Explicit type checking in Python is discouraged (in part because of things like this), so try to use [duck-typing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing#In_Python). Instead of ```isinstance()```, try ```hasattr()```

Comment: OK, that's a workaround. Maybe I'm in a python minority, but I think duck-typing is much weaker than type checking...I guess I was hoping there was an undocumented ABC or something for both types.

Answer (score 0):

Both inherit from _ConnectionBase, which can be found in `multiprocessing/connection.py`. Just do the check with that base.